# Не получается выполнить команду sudo pip install

Tags: python, linux, pip

Хочу в Линукс Минт установить osrframework
При установки пишет

```
alex@alex-Lenovo-ideapad-320-15IAP:~$ sudo -H pip install osrframework
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting osrframework
  Using cached osrframework-0.20.1.tar.gz (209 kB)
    **ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bDobBZ/osrframework/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bDobBZ/osrframework/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-_c2o2O
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-bDobBZ/osrframework/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-bDobBZ/osrframework/setup.py", line 161
        print(f"\t> {cmd}")
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.**
```

Comment: Очевидно, osrframework поддерживает только третий питон, а вы зачем-то пытаетесь ставить во второй. И вообще ставить нужно не в линукс, а в виртуальное окружение вашего проекта.

Comment: Питон я обновил, но проблема остается (пишет все тоже самое). А как это  в виртуальное окружение (извините, я только перешел с виндовс на линукс)?

Comment: Во-первых, обновления третьего питона ни на что не повлияют, если вы запускаете pip от второго питона. Во-вторых, в виндовс тоже нужно было виртуальные окружения всегда использовать

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать

Comment: Надо написать: *sudo -H pip3 install ...* для тертьего питона.

Comment: Вообще запускать pip через sudo - зло. Нужно или ставить пакеты в виртуальное окружение, или запускать pip с флагом --user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Безусловно сначала нужно установить ***python версии 3***:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

В ***python версии 3*** (начиная с 3.4) уже встроен ***pip***, а также ***venv***. Поэтому далее, для безопасной работы создадим виртуальное окружение, которое по дефолту будет использовать ***python версии 3***:

```
python3 -m venv env
```

или (если возникли какие-то ошибки):

```
python3 -m venv --without-pip env
```

После этого запустим наше окружение, где по дефолту будет использоваться ***python версии 3***:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

***(env)*** в командной строке подтверждает, что виртуальное окружение запущено. Далее мы запускаем установку требуемого пакета через ***pip*** следующим образом:

```
pip install имя_пакета
```

В случае, если не хочется заморачиваться с виртуальным окружением, то после установки ***python версии 3*** достаточно воспользоваться командой:

```
python3 -m pip install *имя пакета*
```

Надеюсь поможет)

Answer (score 0):

```
Обнови для начала Питон , в инструкции на Git-Hub всё сказано https://github.com/i3visio/osrframework/blob/master/doc/INSTALL.md , а потом ещё раз попробуй установить , уже по принципу
-----------
>pip3 --version
-------
>python get-pip.py
--------
>wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`
--------
>sudo python get-pip.py
-----
>pip install osrframework --user
------
>echo $PATH
---------------

Если вы не можете найти данную папку в предыдущем пункте, вы всегда можете вручную добавить эту папку в  PATH, добавив эти две строки в  ***.bashrc***, как написано  в https://github.com/i3visio/osrframework/issues/187.
-----------
>export PY_USER_BIN=$(python -c 'import site; print(site.USER_BASE + "/bin")')
export PATH=$PY_USER_BIN:$PATH
----------------------
## Тестирование установки ##
--------
>usufy.py -n i3visio febrezo yrubiosec -p twitter facebook
searchfy.py -q "i3visio"
mailfy.py -n i3visio

Обновление фреймворка
---------------------
>pip install osrframework --upgrade --user
------------
>sudo pip install osrframework --upgrade
------------
>sudo pip install osrframework --upgrade --pre

-----------------------------------
##  P.S Если есть возможность , то перейди на Kali Linux , ведь  Оsrframework является инструментом именно Kali ##
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло. Наверно точно перейду на Kali Linux:)